# angularjs fetching json using http

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I am new to angularjs,

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html ng-app="myapp">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Angularjs project</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
var myapp=angular.module('myapp',[]);
myapp.controller('myctrl', function ($scope,$http) {
$http.get('countries.json').success(function(data){
$scope.countries=data;
});
});
</script>
<body>
<div ng-controller="myctrl">
<table>
<tr>
<th>country</th>
<th>population</th>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="country in coutries">
<td>{{country.name}}</td>
<td>{{country.population}}</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And i have a json file, when it run, it doesn't work.

When i referred in google, they are saying server.js or install node.js something like that.

I just confused,what should i follow, can anyone guide me to fetching json data and display.

any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.,

Comment: hi, for running ajax request you must run your application in a server,
i suggest you to install a local web server like apache and run it from your local host and then ajax request to your json file will be work.
and also you don't need nodejs for this case.

Comment: what is the ajax request? thanks

Comment: yeah.. i already run application in locahost only..

Comment: when you are using $http in angular it's try to make an ajax request whit javascript to the desired destination and get the response back to you,
check this link for more information about ajax http://www.w3schools.com/Ajax/ajax_intro.asp

Comment: if you are running it on localhost and it doesn't work, open console window inside your browser by pressing f12 key and reload the page to send resend the request, there you can see what sending and what is going back as answer to that request, check the status code or any other type of errors

Comment: which server you are using linux or windows for hosting?

Comment: can you upload your entire project some where for me to check whats the problem?
your code seems good. i have to check it on my machine to find the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spelling mistake

```
$scope.countries=data;

<tr ng-repeat="country in coutries">
```

change to :

```
<tr ng-repeat="country in countries">
```

Comment: you made it simple.. so what about that ajax request or mimetype? thanks

Answer (score 0):

you have to include angular.js script. Can't find it in your code. Also  countries.json file must be in the same level as of the above html in project structure.

Comment: close you <head> tag

Comment: Also there is a spelling mistake "$scope.countries=data" and "country in coutries". The spelling of countries is different. You doesn't need any extra config. It is just reading a json file.